# Good A/B testing framework for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ab-testing

I have been looking at Patrick McKenzie's ABingo (http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo) for rails and wondering if there is an equivalent for ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an ASP.NET (MVC) port of the ABingo implementation:

http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlycertain/

- I haven't personally tried it though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4104897/27938 for a recommendation from an actual user

Comment: This is one is more for ASP.NET web forms, could not see good examples on MVC

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with ABingo but you could have a look at http://diy.abtestmaster.com/developers

Disclaimer: It's a framework I have personally developed for A/B testing with asp.net mvc after not being satisfied with what's out there.

Comment: Thanks @Hossein, the link above is mostly about Web Forms, and does not have good examples on MVC